# How to extract result from a json response of slack channel and paste it in other channel

Tags: json, python-2.7, slack-api

I am little stuck where i need to extract the response that i received from a slack channel. The following script simply fetches the result from a slack channel.

```
payload = {'token': 'XXXXXX', 'channel': 'C0L8MGLMN' , 'count': '10'}
r = requests.get('https://slack.com/api/channels.history', params=payload)
print r.status_code
pprint(r.json())
```

This results in :

```
200
{u'has_more': False,
 u'is_limited': True,
 u'messages': [{u'text': u'This is not a test!',
                u'ts': u'1459763505.000003',
                u'type': u'message',
                u'user': u'U03FE3Z7D'},
               {u'subtype': u'bot_message',
                u'text': u'This is a test!',
                u'ts': u'1459750060.000002',
                u'type': u'message',
                u'username': u'facsimile_test'}],
 u'ok': True}
```

I want to extract `username` & the `text` from the json response. And the upload the extracted message fileds to another slack channel. I am not sure how to do so

Comment: Not sure what the exact question here is? You retrieve the value like you would from any dictionary. So to extract the text from the first message you just: `r.json()["messages"][0]["text"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to upload a copy of the messages you extracted from one channel to another channel.

First, to extract a message from the JSON you just need to access it as you would any dictionary in Python. e.g. to extract the first message you use `r.json()["messages"][0]["text"]` (see also comments)

Next, you want to post the messages to the new channel. Unfortunately you can not upload an exact copy to the other channel. But you can repost the content of the extracted messages as new messages to another channel with the API method `chat.postMessage`. Be aware that the message will appear as post from your bot and not the original user. (This depends on the settings of 'as_user' and what kind of token you use.) So you may want to post sth. like "user x said on channel y: text"

See also Slack documentation of `chat.postMessage`.